Define a color interpolation depending on the value of an array
I have this code that works:
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\def\graphsize{6} % It must be 1 less than the number of nodes

\def\precision{
{0,     0,      0,      0.5,    0.2,    0,      0},
{0,     0,      -0.7,   0,      0,      0,      0},
{0,     -0.7,   0,      0.9,    -0.8,   0,      0},
{0.5,   0,      0.9,    0,      -0.5,   0,      0},
{0.2,   0,      -0.8,   -0.5,   0,      1,      -1},
{0,     0,      0,      0,      1,      0,      0.1},
{0,     0,      0,      0,      -1,      0.1,   0},
}

\tikzset{
  myfillrgb/.code args={#1}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rcolor}{int(255*(1-#1)/2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\gcolor}{int(255*(1+#1)/2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\bcolor}{int(255*(1+#1)/2)}
    \definecolor{mycolour}{RGB}{\rcolor, \gcolor, \bcolor}%
    \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/fill=mycolour}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={rectangle,
                                draw=white, very thick, minimum size=1cm}]

    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,\graphsize}{
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,\graphsize}
        {
            \node[box, myfillrgb={{\precision}[\x][\y]}] at (\x,-\y){};
        }
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

It generates this image:

I want to create the same image but using interpolation between arbitrary colors.
However, when I try to do that by replacing the myfillrgb with this:
\tikzset{
  myfillrgb/.code args={#1}{
    % If #1 is 0, just use the gray color
    \ifdim#1 pt=0pt
      \definecolor{mycolour}{RGB}{124, 126, 127}
    % If #1 is negative, interpolate between blue and gray
    % If #1 is positive, interpolate between red and gray
    \else
      \ifdim#1 pt>0pt
        \def\rcolor{int(192-192*#1)}
        \def\gcolor{int(72-72*#1)}
        \def\bcolor{int(41-41*#1)}
      \else
        \def\rcolor{int(0+192*#1)}
        \def\gcolor{int(32+40*#1)}
        \def\bcolor{int(91-50*#1)}
      \definecolor{mycolour}{RGB}{\rcolor, \gcolor, \bcolor}%
    \fi
    \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/fill=mycolour}
  }
}

I get several compilation errors. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

You could let xcolor do the mixing for you:
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\def\graphsize{6} % It must be 1 less than the number of nodes

\def\precision{
{0,     0,      0,      0.5,    0.2,    0,      0},
{0,     0,      -0.7,   0,      0,      0,      0},
{0,     -0.7,   0,      0.9,    -0.8,   0,      0},
{0.5,   0,      0.9,    0,      -0.5,   0,      0},
{0.2,   0,      -0.8,   -0.5,   0,      1,      -1},
{0,     0,      0,      0,      1,      0,      0.1},
{0,     0,      0,      0,      -1,      0.1,   0},
}

\definecolor{mycolora}{RGB}{192,72,41}
\definecolor{mycolorb}{RGB}{0,32,91}

\tikzset{
  myfillrgb/.code args={#1}{
  \pgfmathsign{#1}
  \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0
    \pgfmathparse{#1*100}
    \colorlet{myfill}{mycolora!\pgfmathresult!gray}
  \else
    \pgfmathparse{#1*100*-1}
    \colorlet{myfill}{mycolorb!\pgfmathresult!gray}
  \fi
  \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/fill=myfill}
  }
}

\begin{document}

{\color{mycolora}\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\color{mycolorb}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={rectangle,
                                draw=white, very thick, minimum size=1cm}]

    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,\graphsize}{
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,\graphsize}
        {
            \node[box, myfillrgb={{\precision}[\x][\y]}] at (\x,-\y){};
        }
    }

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}


